# Thermal conductivity and diffusivity of diatomite (also known as diatomaceous earth or kieselguhr)

Tags: temperature, thermodynamics

Cross-posted [on MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11965/5) and  [on Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/177860/27342).

Does anyone know where can I find measured thermal conductivity and thermal diffusivity of diatomite for different temperatures? I'm looking for the temperature dependency for temperatures higher than 300K. The upper temperature limit shall be at least 1000K, but more is better. All I have found is thermal conductivity in "Touloukian, Y. S., et al. "Thermophysical properties of matter - The TPRC data series. Volume 2. Thermal conductivity - nonmetallic solids. (1971)". I'm still missing data on thermal diffusivity though, and I'd like to see more data on thermal conductivity, if available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If this community doesn't have a useful response in a few days, perhaps request a transfer to chemistry SE, as I'd think such data is right in their wheelhouse (though certainly also plenty of tie ins to geology and such here)

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged on the Stack Exchange network. There are duplicates on Matter Modeling (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11965) and Chemistry (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/177860). I have already closed the latter.